# Is there an access modifier that limits to a solution?

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

In my .NET solution, I have two projects: one main project and a project for running tests against the main project. In my project, I have several methods that I'd like to keep "private", but would also like to run tests for. Is there an access method that could limit these functions to just inside of my solution?

Comment: One could argue that you should only test your public API, but you could use internal and InternalsVisibleTo to allow the test project to see them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking for the [InternalsVisibleTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

This attributes lets you specify other assemblies that should have access to types and methods that are internal to your assembly. So, in your main project AssemblyInfo.cs file (or any other source file), you can specify that your test project is a 'friend assembly' and should have access to the internals of your main project:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MainProject.Tests")]
```

On a side note, as pointed out by Alexei, if your MainProject is signed with a strong name key, any 'friend' assembly must also be signed. This is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Although, as mentioned in another comment. Best practice is to test your assembly by using its public API.

Comment: Side note: `InternalsVisibleTo` approach does not work for many people due to strong signing requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to make `internal` types and methods visible to selected assemblies.

However, you should try to design your API so that it can be tested using only the public interface.

Answer (score 2):

You should seriously think back about the architecture of your solution. This is a smell that often shows that your class does too much things at once.

A simple fix is to extract this responsibility (those private methods) to another class where they then become `public` and are testable out of the box...

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to limit access to "just solution".

The reason is solution is simply group of projects. One project can be in any number of solutions. So even if you "limit" access to projects included in one solution you/someone else can create another solution that somehow will need to magically get access to methods.

Additionally built assembly does not include any information on what solution it was part of - so there is no information at run time to check access.

---

To you particular problem - `InternalsVisibleTo` (as shown in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34138913/477420)) will give access to internal methods to projects you allow (requires strongly signed assemblies) or refactor your code to avoid need for testing private methods.